# How to crop SVG?

Tags: linux, command-line, svg

How do you crop all empty space from an SVG file, specifically from the command line?

I have several SVG files formatted to the standard A2 letter document size, and I need to bulk crop them down so their view box is the same as the minimum bounding box for their contents.

I can do this in Inkscape using the "Resize Page to Selection" option, but I don't see any way to access this function from the command-line.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
inkscape --batch-process \
  --verb "EditSelectAll;FitCanvasToSelection;FileSave;FileQuit" \
  filename.svg
```

Under Mac OS the following command line worked:

```
inkscape -g --verb="FitCanvasToDrawing;FileSave;FileQuit" filename.svg
```

Note that if I provide three different `--verb` option (which is recommended by the other answers), it didn't work (probably, only the last verb was executed).

Comment: Is there a way to add padding (let say 5mm per each side) to the output image?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the "Resize Page to Selection" option is available via command line! Check it out here: https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2013/03/inkscape-cropping-svg-files-on-the-command-line/

```
inkscape --verb=FitCanvasToDrawing --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit *.svg
```

(Use `FileClose` for older versions of Inkscape.)

Comment: But it warns: "WARNING: ignoring verb FitCanvasToDrawing - GUI required for this verb."

Comment: This didn't work for me with `*.svg`: the files remained unchanged. I had to loop over them like `for file in *.svg; do inkscape ... "$file"; done`

Answer (score 4):

For new `inkscape` versions only this works:

```
inkscape --actions "select-all;fit-canvas-to-selection" --export-overwrite input.svg
```

This would overwrite the file. You can use option `-o <new_file>` for creating new file.

Comment: It worked for me, but how can I use it to process multiple files?

Comment: I would just do Bash loop over files you want, something like `cd my-svg-files; for f in *.svg ; do inkscape ... "$f" ; done`

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape 1.2+ introduces *actions* and removes *verbs*, so you'll have to use

```
inkscape \
  --actions "select-all;fit-canvas-to-selection;export-filename:newname.svg;export-do" \
  input.svg
```

Answer (score 1):

*Because this page shows up when one searches for “crop SVG”, I believe it is worth updating it.*

Note that verbs have been removed in Inkscape 1.1 and that one should use actions instead. It is also possible to achieve the cropping using only export options. With Inkscape >= 1.0, this would be:

```
inkscape --batch-process --export-area-drawing --export-plain-svg \
    --export-filename=/path/to/output.svg /path/to/input.svg
```

With Inscape < 1.0:

```
inkscape --without-gui --export-area-drawing \
    --export-plain-svg=/path/to/output.svg /path/to/input.svg
```

Note that, even if this does not use the GUI, due to how Inkscape is implemented, this still requires a lot of things to be available (eg. the bus system, a writable home, an X server, etc.) and will not work in a restricted environment.